# How to run the collectstatic script after deployment to amazon elastic beanstalk?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I have a django app that is deployed on aws elastic beanstalk when I want to deploy I need to run the migrate, and the collectstatic script.

I have created `01_build.config` in `.ebextensions` directory and this is its content

```
commands:
  migrate:
    command: "python manage.py migrate"
    ignoreErrors: true
  collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

but still, it is not running these scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to run these scripts *after* the app has been set up, in which case you need to use the key `container_commands` rather than `commands`. [From the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html):

> The commands run before the application and web server are set up and the application version file is extracted.

and

> Container commands run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version archive has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed. Non-container commands and other customization operations are performed prior to the application source code being extracted.